# Crontab fails to run a shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, nuance

there's a command to start up a service which is
`su -s /bin/bash nuance -c '$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=$NLPS_HOME/config/log4j2.xml -jar $NLPS_HOME/lib/nlps.jar --spring.config.location=$NLPS_HOME/config/,$NUANCE_DATA_DIR/system/config/User-nlps01.properties  watcher.RestartOnFailure=FALSE watcher.SendAlarmsToWatcher=FALSE > /dev/null 2>&1 &'` I want this command to run at startup in my rhel 7 linux. So I tried crontab, which is @reboot sh /execute/nlp.sh

But it doesn't work, I don't know why. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong I'm so stuck
Inside nlp.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/su -s /bin/bash nuance -c '$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=$NLPS_HOME/config/log4j2.xml -jar $NLPS_HOME/lib/nlps.jar --spring.config.location=$NLPS_HOME/config/,$NUANCE_DATA_DIR/system/config/User-nlps01.properties  watcher.RestartOnFailure=FALSE watcher.SendAlarmsToWatcher=FALSE > /dev/null 2>&1 &'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `$JAVA_HOME`,`$NLPS_HOME` and `$NUANCE_DATA_DIR` environment variables are needed to be defined and exported before the execution of the script.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/home
export NUANCE_DATA_DIR=/path/to/nuance/dir
export NLPS_HOME=/path/to/npls/home
```

Comment: That actually makes sense and I did put the environment variables but still no luck, tired even giving full paths. I don't know why the command works executing directly and straight of a shell file but doesn't work on crontab, systemd service or even /etc/init.d/

Comment: there might be several reasons. you can check cron logs. for ubuntu ` grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double quotes to interpolate variables. Single quotes won't interpolate anything, but double quotes will.

```
/bin/su -s /bin/bash nuance -c "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=$NLPS_HOME/config/log4j2.xml -jar $NLPS_HOME/lib/nlps.jar --spring.config.location=$NLPS_HOME/config/,$NUANCE_DATA_DIR/system/config/User-nlps01.properties  watcher.RestartOnFailure=FALSE watcher.SendAlarmsToWatcher=FALSE > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

From Bash manual:

> [3.1.2.2 Single Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)

Enclosing characters in single quotes (`'`) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

> [3.1.2.3 Double Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes (`"`) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, and, when history expansion is enabled, `!`. The characters `$` and `` ` `` retain their special meaning within double quotes (see [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions)). The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: `$`, `` ` ``, `"`, `\`, or newline. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an `!` appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the `!` is not removed.

The special parameters `*` and `@` have special meaning when in double quotes (see [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)).

Comment: Yes I tried putting double quotes. Is there any way I could execute this command at the startup or even call it by any shell? I have no clue how to